# Python 3.5: Adding a margin to a tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

Code:

```
from data import *
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("python")
root.geometry("400x400")

label1 = Label(root, text="Type a thing:")
entry1 = Entry(root)
button_1 = Button(root, text="Sign In", command=execute1)

label1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(0,15))
entry1.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_1.grid(row=2, sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

I want to add margin to the window. Like adding margin in CSS.
I tried this:

```
root.grid(padx=20, pady=20)
```

But i'm getting this error:

> TypeError: wm_grid() got an unexpected keyword argument 'padx'

I'm using Python 3.5, how can i do that?

Comment: Put elements in a Frame.

Comment: grid() docs tell you what to use http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not run this code:

```
root.grid(padx=20, pady=20)
```

Because both `padx` and `pady` options are used to add a padding to place around the widget in a **cell**. This means, you can use these two options for widgets positioned within the `tkinter.TK()` main window using the `grid()` method.

But for the main widget root itself you can not add any padding because a padding is added respectively to a `tkinter.TK()` cell.

Comment: TypeError: wm_grid() got an unexpected keyword argument 'padx'